# document.getElementById() returns null when using mozrepl (but not in firebug)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox3.6

I'm trying to use the [mozrepl](http://wiki.github.com/bard/mozrepl/) Firefox extension to give me a Javascript REPL from within emacs.

I think I've got it set up correctly. I can interact with the REPL from emacs and can explore the document pretty much as described in the tutorial pages. The problem comes when I try to do something really simple, like get a context to a canvas element:

```
repl> document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d")
!!! TypeError: document.getElementById("mycanvas") is null

Details:

  message: document.getElementById("mycanvas") is null
  fileName: chrome://mozrepl/content/repl.js -> file:///C:/Users/teamonkey/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/chfdenuz.default/mozrepl.tmp.js
  lineNumber: 1
  stack:
    @chrome://mozrepl/content/repl.js -> file:///C:/Users/teamonkey/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/chfdenuz.default/mozrepl.tmp.js:1
  name: TypeError
```

It's not just that particular instance: *any* call to getElementById will just return null.

If I start up firebug I can enter the same thing and it will return a valid context, but I'd really like to get the REPL working in emacs. I don't think this is a bug but I've probably not configured mozrepl correctly. Can anyone help?

Mozrepl 1.0, Firefox 3.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start, you are in the context of **browser window** itself, not any particular document. You have access to chrome elements (menus, toolbars, tabs, etc). The `document` object currently refers to browser window.

To switch context to the document in active tab use:

```
repl.enter(content)
```

Now `document` object is the document loaded in active tab, so you have access to its DOM tree nad can manipulate it.