# Why is getElementsByTagName returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom

I'm trying to call `document.getElementsByTagName`, and I'm getting back `undefined` as a result, no matter what parameter I pass.  (Even if I pass "*".)

I tried Googling for it, but all the search results were about elements of the getElementsByTagName result array being undefined.  What I'm getting is `undefined` as the result itself, and it's driving me up the wall.

Does anyone know what can cause this?  (Using Firefox 12.0.  In Chrome I get the expected results.)

EDIT: OK, here's sample code:

```
function buttonClick(){
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var msg = document.getElementById('message');
   var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
   var button, i;
   for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i){
      button = buttons[i];
      msg.removeChild(button);
   }

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4){
            handleResult(xhr.responseText, msg);
        }
   };
   xhr.open("POST", location.href, true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xhr.send("cmd=MyCommand");
}
```

And the `getElementsByTagName` always returns `undefined`, whether I trace it in Firebug's Script tab or call it from the Console tab. (Also in Firebug, since this seems to be confusing people.  Apparently there are way too many consoles floating around.).

As proof, here's what I've been getting when I tried to use the Firebug console:

```
>>> document.getElementsByTagName("button");
undefined
>>> msg.getElementsByTagName("button");
undefined
>>> msg.getElementsByTagName
getElementsByTagName()
>>> msg.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON");
undefined
>>> msg.getElementsByTagName("*");
undefined
>>> document.getElementsByTagName("*");
undefined
>>> document.getElementsByTagName("body");
undefined
```

The markup is (or ought to be) irrelevant.  It's a valid, well-formed HTML page with some buttons and other elements on it.  This JS function is attached to the `onclick` of one of the buttons.  But it looks something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
blah
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myJS.js"></script>
<div id="page-container">
   <div id="message"><button onclick="buttonClick();">Button 1</button><button onclick="ButtonClick2()">Button 2</button></div>

</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: That method should never return `undefined`, even when there are no matches. Are you testing in the console, or on a page?

Comment: Have you tried running the JavaScript *after* the elements are loaded in the DOM? Putting the `<script>...</script>` just before the closing `</body>` tag? Or in a `<body onload="functionName()">` onload event?

Comment: Fiddle demos: http://jsfiddle.net/5nQDc/

Comment: What does the markup look like?

Comment: I don't see where you're logging to the console. Perhaps a typo? Perhaps `console.log(button)`, leaving off the `s`? Perhaps you're logging outside the variable scope? Perhaps you're affected by the asynchronous nature of xhr requests?

Comment: @amnotiam: I'm not logging anything to the console. I'm trying to use the REPL in Firebug's "console" tab to execute the command.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for a demo? Without examining the actual code in practice, I'm not sure what to say.

Comment: why don't you add a `console.log( buttons )` right below it

Comment: Do you get a "not defined" error or an `undefined` value? Are you sure Firebug's console tab doesn't execute in the global scope, trying to access `window.buttons`?

Comment: @MasonWheeler: If you're invoking the `buttonClick` function from the REPL, then yes, you'll get `undefined` because the function returns nothing. Aside from that, I can't tell how you're actually doing the test. ...or are you setting a breakpoint in the function?

Comment: @pimvdb: I get an `undefined` value.  The function is defined. I already checked that.

Comment: @amnotiam: That's not what I said.  I'm calling `document.getElementsByTagName("button");` from the console.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: "The function is defined" - are you getting `undefined` as a return value from the `buttonClick` function? That's expected.

Comment: What does the console show you when you just type `document.getElementsByTagName` (not a function call; just a reference to the function)?  Is it `[native code]` ?

Comment: @MasonWheeler: You weren't explicit about what you were doing in the console. If you're executing `getElementsByTagName` directly in the console, but you're doing `var foo = document.getElem...`, then it will show up as `undefined`.

Comment: @pimvdb: PLEASE READ WHAT I SAID! ARGH!  **I am getting `undefined` as a result from document.getElementsByTagName`. I do understand the basic principles of writing code!**

Comment: "I am getting undefined as a result from `document.getElementsByTagName`" - this is simply impossible. You must be doing something extra which might not be obvious, but which is crucial to answering the question.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Take it easy. This stuff is simple, but you're providing smatterings of information. If you're typing something into the console, you should copy/paste exactly what you're typing into your question.

Comment: @MasonWheeler it's important to understand that nobody else is getting that result. The most likely reasons are that there's something else about your code that's causing the problem, or that your debugging technique is flawed.

Comment: Is this working like you're expecting? http://jsfiddle.net/WshUR/

Comment: As well as using the `msg.getElementsByTagName()` context: http://jsfiddle.net/WshUR/1/

Comment: @Jared Farrish: `NodeList`s change length automatically as you remove their items, so due to the loop you're missing an item each time. Try http://jsfiddle.net/WshUR/2/.

Comment: @pimvdb - At this point, I'm just trying to replicate the Mason's actual code (also note the use of `++1`, which is his as well).

Comment: It doesn't seem that the code in the question has anything to do with the issue at hand. If the issue is observed by directly calling `gEBTN` in the console, then I'm not sure how the question's code is relevant. EDIT: The question has been updated.

Comment: @pimvdb: That's a good point. I should replace that with a `WHILE` loop, once I actually have an array to process.

Comment: OK, it's a bit off-topic indeed, never mind. @Mason Wheeler: So it is a function but it does return `undefined`. The native function should never do that. What does `document.getElementsByTagName + ""` give?

Comment: I'm more curious to know what happens if you log from your actual code. `console.log(document.getEle...)`. The console isn't representative of anything except itself and its own idiosyncrasies. Ultimately it doesn't matter what the console shows, but rather what the actual code does.

Comment: Is `document` there in the context you're calling `document.getElementById()`? Does it give you a value you expect?

Comment: @Jared: Yes.  "the context" is Firebug.  `document` is exactly what you'd expect.  So is every other script element.

Comment: @MasonWheeler do the linked jsfiddle examples work for you?

Comment: If I do `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('marquee'));` in Firebug (1.9.2, FF12), I get `[]`. Check your Firebug settings and/or try reinstalling. I've seen people complain that at times Firebug gets flaky and needs a refresh, stuff like this.

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, so that's even stranger.

Comment: Try this in safe mode, perhaps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**edit:**

This is a bug in firebug and is fixed by upgrading to [1.10.0a7](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/firebug/woLuJAkRmPY)

---

Because it is impossible for this method to return `undefined`, there are 2 possibilities:

- Your debugging tools are lying to you
- `document.getElementsByTagName` is not referencing the original host object. It should print
  `function getElementsByTagName() {[native code]}` when referenced in console.

You should be able to reliably to see if it's in fact `undefined` (in firefox) with this:

```
delete window.alert;
window.alert(buttons);
```

The `delete` is a NOOP if `window.alert` is already referencing the original host object, otherwise
it will restore it.

If it *alerts* `undefined`, you should be able to do

```
delete document.getElementsByTagName
```

to restore the host object reference.

All console references here refer to the built in Web Console that comes with firefox by default.

Comment: I think this is closest to a reasonable explanation. Though there must be some code being loaded to shadow the host objects.

Comment: Nope.  There's no code being loaded to alter any host objects.  This is a very simple page with very simple scripting.  If I was doing anything fancy like that, that would definitely be the first suspect!

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: I'm sorry for bugging you but could you please post what `document.getElementsByTagName + ""` gives? Just to assure it's the native function.

Comment: @MasonWheeler that's cool. There is still the point of debugging tools not working properly, so you could validate that point by just adding the simple alert code, running your page and seeing what it alerts.

Comment: @pimvdb: `"function getElementsByTagName() { [native code] }"`

Comment: @MasonWheeler See if you have the same problem as him https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/firebug/woLuJAkRmPY

Comment: @Esailija: Aha!  Yes, I'm seeing exactly the same issue as that guy.  I'll have to update Firebug and see if it's fixed.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I see you have accepted so I assume upgrading fixed the issue, I have edited it in to the answer so it gets more google visibility :P

Comment: I'm confused. That Firebug issue also impacts actual JavaScript code not run from Firebug?

Comment: @amnotiam: No, it looks like there was an additional problem in my script that was causing it to fail.  But with a broken debugging tool, I wasn't able to find it.  I got it working now.

Comment: Developer tools/consoles can be handy, but also can be unreliable/misleading. If you're getting odd results, consider that to be suspect #1, and shift your testing directly into your code as much as possible. That's why I wrote above: *"The console isn't representative of anything except itself and its own idiosyncrasies..."* and so on.

Comment: @amnotiam agree, good example of that is the gotcha in chrome console where you log object references directly and the state snapshot is not actually taken until you expand it manually in console.

Comment: `getElementsByName` is/was also affected by this bug.

Comment: In Chrome deleting `window.alert` doesn't restore original function.

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem when I made a difficult to see syntax error.  I used **parenthesis** when I should have used square **brackets**

Wrong:

```
selectedItem._element.childNodes(0).getElementsByTagName('input').item();
```

Right:

```
selectedItem._element.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName('input').item();
```

See the difference?  Note, the top syntax works is older versions of IE, like IE8, but it doesn't work in ie10, ie11, Edge etc

Answer (score 0):

Isn't REPL a stand-alone, browser-independent JavaScript environment? While, in your case, in just happens to be running in your browser as a plugin, it's supposed to mimic a "clean room" per say...

To summarize this guy's answer: [document.getElementById() returns null when using mozrepl (but not in firebug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485866/document-getelementbyid-returns-null-when-using-mozrepl-but-not-in-firebug)

By default, you'r in the **browser's** context, not the document's.

Try this to switch to the document instead:

```
repl.enter(content)
```

Comment: REPL can refer to any read-eval-print-loop. The browsers' developer's console is usually a REPL, meaning you can type in code, and it will eval it and print the result. In the brower's console, you still have access to the same DOM as that of the regular JS environment.

Comment: It's always given me expected results before.  And I get the same problem when running the actual script.

Comment: Seemed to have worked for *that* guy. Thought it'd be worth a shot! I guess we'll keep on truck'n.

Comment: I'm not using mozrepl, I'm using Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

You can't alert an `Array`, you should do a for loop to alert it. Example:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, c = x.length ; i < c ; i++) {
    alert('Element n° ' + (i + 1) + ' : ' + x[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is also raised when we try to access element without array index. Because document.getElementsByTagName('tag') returns an array.