# TypeError: this.Rows is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, typeerror

When i click the search button it always alert me "TypeError: this.Rows is undefined

for (var i = 0, row; row = this.Rows[i], rowText = this.RowsText[i]; i++) { "

Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        //define the table search as an object, which can implement both functions and properties
        window.tableSearch = {};

        //initialize the search, setup the current object
        tableSearch.init = function() {
            //define the properties I want on the tableSearch object
            this.Rows = document.getElementById('data').getElementsByTagName('TR');
            this.RowsLength = tableSearch.Rows.length;
            this.RowsText = [];

            //loop through the table and add the data to
            for (var i = 0; i < tableSearch.RowsLength; i++) {
                this.RowsText[i] = (tableSearch.Rows[i].innerText) ? tableSearch.Rows[i].innerText.toUpperCase() : tableSearch.Rows[i].textContent.toUpperCase();
            }
        }

        //onlys shows the relevant rows as determined by the search string
        tableSearch.runSearch = function() {
            //get the search term
            this.Term = document.getElementById('textBoxSearch').value.toUpperCase();

            //loop through the rows and hide rows that do not match the search query
            for (var i = 0, row; row = this.Rows[i], rowText = this.RowsText[i]; i++) {
                row.style.display = ((rowText.indexOf(this.Term) != -1) || this.Term === '') ? '' : 'none';
            }
        }

        //runs the search
        tableSearch.search = function(e) {
            //checks if the user pressed the enter key, and if they did then run the search
            var keycode;
            if (window.event) { keycode = window.event.keyCode; }
            else if (e) { keycode = e.which; }
            else { return false; }
            if (keycode == 13) {
                tableSearch.runSearch();
            }
            else { return false; }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most probable causes to that problem are:

1. You never called your `init` function. Make sure to call it after your HTML has loaded and before using `Rows` the first time.
2. [There is a Firefox bug where `getElementsByTagName('TR');` returns `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775489/why-is-getelementsbytagname-returning-undefined). make sure that that is not your problem.

Comment: In first case, it should either return an empty array or throw an error stating cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName` of null. Probably second one.

Comment: @Mathew Thanks for noticing. Fixed it. :)